# strange value of totalVolume

Tags: python, python-3.x

I create a a python code which show the total volume of selected elements from a list.

The strange thing  is that i got an error value of the total volume , but when i put printf(totalvolume) before i got a correct value.

Here the code :

```
class FractionalKnapSack:
  
    """Time Complexity O(n log n)"""
    @staticmethod
    def getMaxValue(wt, val, conv, capacity,m):
        """function to get maximum value """
        iVal = []
        for i in range(len(wt)):
            
            iVal.append(ItemValue(wt[i], val[i], conv[i], i))
            
  
        # sorting items by value
        
        iVal.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: x.val)
        iVal = iVal[0:m]
        
  
        totalValue = 0
        totalVolume = 0
        for i in iVal:
            
            
            curWt = int(i.wt)
            
            
            curVal = int(i.val)
            if capacity - curWt >= 0:
                
                
                
                capacity -= curWt
                totalVolume += curWt
                
                
                print("totalVolume", totalVolume)
                
                
            else:
                
                
                fraction = capacity / curWt
              
                totalVolume += curWt * fraction
                capacity = int(capacity - (curWt * fraction))
                
                break
            
              
        return totalVolume    
    
    
# Driver Code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    wt = [20, 50, 40, 90]
    val = [60, 40, 100, 20]
    capacity = 160
    m = 2
    conv = [60, 40, 1000, 120]
  
    # Function call
    maxVolume= FractionalKnapSack.getMaxValue(wt, val, conv, capacity, m)
    print("Maximum value in Knapsack =", maxValue)
```

Can you help me to fix this problem please?  thanks

Comment: did you debug the error in else case? try to see from which part you are getting totalVolume and try to debug there

Comment: Without all those empty lines, maybe we wouldn't have to scroll and could see the whole code at once...

Comment: @KellyBundy the problem is solved, how can I close it?

Comment: @buddy I see you answered yourself. You should be able to *delete* the question if you don't think it's valuable for others or wait two days until you can *accept* your answer if you do think it's valuable for others.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you  , I just found the cause of the error :

I should replace maxValue by maxVolume

```
print("Maximum value in Knapsack =", maxVolume)
```